# I don't understand why my graph of the variance of the Sun's true noon is so bumpy

Tags: orbital-motion, astronomy, solar-system

I understand that the true noon, defined as the sun reaching its highest point in the sky, varies from the noon we have on our clocks.  I understand the impact that the eliptic orbit has on the speed of the earth and why that would lead to a true noon happening after 12pm in February and before 12 pm in late autumn but when I map the true noon I notice 2 bumps and it's the second variation I don't understand.

Below is a graph showing the time of the mid-point between sunrise and sunset that I have assumed to be the time of the true noon.  [image: True Noon, London enter image description here2017-18 adjusted to remove impact of British Summer Time]

What I don't understand is why the true noon starts moving back to before the clock noon in late spring only to move back to after noon in late summer.

Comment: Does this help? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/469869/123208

Comment: How did you create that graph? It's very bumpy when you zoom in, it should be smooth.

Comment: See [Equation of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_time).